# Is there a way I can access R via the web?

Tags: r, web-applications, statistics

This question hasn't been asked yet. Some solutions probably have been proposed though to other (similar) problems. My apologies for that.

My question is: as a student I work a lot with R, but sometimes I'd like to just access a browser, go to a website and type in a few R commands and then have some quick results back (e.g. calculating my grades on a laptop of a friend).

Now I could have my pc up and running all night, etc. But I'm more wondering about if there are any web applications that simulate the R console. I found one, but it doesn't work (which was the first or second hit on google).

Does anyone have any ideas? It might be that something like this (or something similar close to the R language on the web) doesn't exist.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could try using an online compiler for quick testing purposes. [Ideone](http://ideone.com/) comes to mind as a suitable option. Select the R language from menu on the left, enter the code you would like to test, then hit submit to see the output.

This also has the benefit of allowing you to share results from testing short code snippets by copy pasting the URL, which can be especially handy here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 10):

Like Andrew Dempsey suggested, RStudio Server works like a charm on AWS and Ubuntu Server. I have a private image running for a statistics class—everyone has their own Unix account and can log in to that account through the web interface at anytime. It's fantastic.

Answer (score 5):

What about a combination of:

- micro instance from Amazon AWS (free for 12 months) http://aws.amazon.com/
- RStudio web server: http://rstudio.org/
- Use BioConducter AMI set set up 1 & 2: http://bioconductor.org/help/bioconductor-cloud-ami/

Answer (score 4):

While @Perception's suggestion of [Ideone](http://ideone.com/) seems to the best answer for your specific needs (*type in a few R commands and then have some quick results back*"), I would also suggest [The Sage Notebook](http://sagenb.org/).

From their website:

*With the Sage Notebook anyone can create, collaborate on, and publish interactive worksheets. In a worksheet, one can write code using Sage, Python, and other software included in Sage.* [Yes, R is one of them.]

Answer (score 3):

2 ideas spring to mind:

1) set up a free AWS micro image and put rstudio web server on it. This will give you a free web based R environment for 12 months

2) somewhere in these forums, I think, or it might be on the rstudio forums, are instructions on how to host r and r studio on a flash drive.

Comment: The setup is described, for instance, here: http://www.r-bloggers.com/rstudio-in-the-cloud-for-dummies/

Answer (score 0):

What about ssh? There are even ssh clients for android now.

Answer (score 0):

This may be overkill for "type in a few commands"...

You could leave a desktop running with your favorite editor/IDE and `R`.
Then remotely access it with e.g. [realVNC](http://www.realvnc.com/), which is now available as a free plugin for the chrome/ chromium browser. The refresh time is generally fast enough that you can work in close to real time. *And* you can access hardware that's too big to haul around in a laptop.